# Apply css class to specific element depending on state

Tags: css, reactjs

I have React component, with state managed by redux, ul list and a css-class. I want to apply class to one of li elements, depending on state. For instance, if myStateProp = a, apply css class to first li, if myStateProp = b, apply class to second li and so on. But I'm not sure how to do it properly.

For now I solved this problem like this:

```
<ul>
    <li className={this.props.myStateProp ==="a" ? "myCssClass" : ""}>A</li>
    <li className={this.props.myStateProp ==="b" ? "myCssClass" : ""}>B</li>
    <li className={this.props.myStateProp ==="c" ? "myCssClass" : ""}>C</li>
</ul>
```

But I don’t really like this approach, seems too many copied code. Maybe there is a way to do it more neatly?

Comment: Looks like a valid solution

Comment: I don't see how you could do it any other way, unless you had the values of the li in a var and then did a loop

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll stick to this solution then. Thanks for verification

Comment: You can try [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

Comment: Maybe it would help if you give us a bit more code/context. There are always many possible solutions. Some more, some less elegant. From your code it looks like you are assigning the class according to the click or some similar event. If that's the case, you can maybe have some `handleClick(e)` function which will assign the class on `e.target`. It's really hard to tell without proper context.

Comment: @ickyrr, yes that may be a solution:) for now i just wanted to understand how to deal with it without additional libraries

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac , class is assigned according to current state. And state is changed  via onClick function. Could you please explain your solution?

Comment: @AnnieH. Like I said, it would really help to see more code. At least, how did you structure your props. Meanwhile, I think Matt's answer is also really nice solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there's nothing inherently wrong with your code, you could simplify it with a class method `ternary` statement and return `"myCssClass"` or `null`.

```
class Example extends PureComponent {

  isActive = item => this.props.someProp === item ? "myCssClass" : null  

  render = () => (
    <ul>
      <li className={isActive("a")}>A</li>
      <li className={isActive("b")}>B</li>
      <li className={isActive("c")}>C</li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Or, take it one step further and simplify your `li` elements (while less repetitive, it does abstract what's happening):

```
const listItems = ["a","b","c"];

class Example extends PureComponent {

  isActive = item => this.props.someProp === item ? "myCssClass" : null  

  render = () => (
    <ul>
      {listItems.map(item => (
        <li key={item} className={isActive(item)}>
          { item.toUpperCase() }
        </li> 
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can create function which will return classname

```
const classNames = (data)=>{
   swtich/case/if... what you want

   return 'SomeClassName'
}

<li className={this.classNames(dataFromStore)}>C</li>
```

Comment: But isn't it assumes that I should have different classes for every element?

Comment: yep, sorry a bit unclear your question. Unswer upper is good for you!